# Progressbar Android Coloreando una Imagen

Tags: android, imagen, progressbar

necesito hacer lo siguiente con un progressbar, quiero que el progressbar vaya coloreando una imagen a medida que este aumente, algo así como la siguiente imagen.
[image: Imagen coloreada por un progressbar]

Esto lo voy a hacer en un layout para un ListView, prefiero librerías nativas pero si conocen alguna buena igualmente la voy a probar

Comment: Acabo de hacer una solución para esto, buscare hacerlo librería porque la idea está interesante

Comment: Hola, te invitamos a leer [ask] y agregar en tus preguntas lo que has tratado o investigado, revisa [ask] por favor, saludos

Answer (score 0):

He creado una librería que soluciona el problema ya que se me hizo interesante. Solo necesitas descargarla

implementation 'io.github.rockbass2560:imageprogress:1.0.1'

Despues puede agregar un ImageView con la imagen que deseas transformar

[image: primer ejemplo]

Para incrementar el valor utiliza el value
[image: segundo ejemplo]

Muestra de la aplicacion con un value de 25
[image]

Muestra de la aplicacion con un value de 75
[image]

Comment: Gracias por tu  contribución, ayúdanos a responder preguntas que hayan sido creadas en base a [ask], saludos.